# Slideshow start delay in JavaScript script

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I want to develop a JavaScript image slideshow that will start looping after 4 second delay and loop forever.

This is my script, please tell me what's wrong in my script.
HTML part

```
<div id="slideshow_main"> <img id="im1" src="images/slideshow/101.jpg" alt="Image 1"/> <img id="im2" src="images/slideshow/102.jpg" alt="Image 2"/> </div>
```

JavaScript part

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var image_no001 = document.getElementById("im1");
var image_no002 = document.getElementById("im2");

function slider(){ // Slider begin
       setInterval(
           function(){
          image_no001.style.display = "none";
       },2000);

       setInterval(
           function(){
          image_no002.style.display = "none";
       },4000);
} // Slider end

   setTimeout(slider(), 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: `setTimeout(slider(), 5000);` should be `setTimeout(slider, 5000);`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the function reference/name to `setTimeout` not the **output of the function**.

`setTimeout(slider, 5000)`; not `setTimeout(slider(), 5000);`

`slider()` will invoke the function and in `setTimeout(slider(), 5000);` the return value of the `function slider`, which is `undefined` will be passed to `setTimeout`

`setTimeout` will invoke the function at the desired time, **5000 mili seconds or 5 seconds in the OP**.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like the following:

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/h3fog6oz/)

## JS

```
var img0 = document.getElementById('img0');
img0.style.display = 'none';
var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
img1.style.display = 'block';

setInterval(function () {
    img0.style.display = img0.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
    img1.style.display = img1.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
}, 3000);
```

## HTML

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/cats/" alt="" id="img0">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/401/201/cats/" alt="" id="img1">
```